# Avoid Selenium to be detected by javascript duck typing in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to change Selenium properties in order to avoid its own detection by duck typing method in Javascript?

Last time I was hardly looking to make Selenium to be fully undetected and identically to Chrome. Almost succeed but just found this new detection method which I cannot bypass: duck typing in Javascript.

Here is the Javascript detection code:

```
// Opera 8.0+
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1 - 71
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;


var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>';
output += 'isEdge: ' + isEdge + '<br>';
output += 'isBlink: ' + isBlink + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/6spj1059/
Look what are the results for this js code in real Chrome browser:
[results for real Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAg82.png)

While all of them are FALSE when open the same **jsfiddle** link in Selenium.

Here is what I did into Python. I tried to change window title in python by asserting it as Chrome since just by setting it directly isn't possible. Also tried to first navigate to the chrome://newtab url and after that to the url I want but also fails.

```
browser.get("chrome://newtab")
try:
    assert u'New Tab' in browser.title
    print "Assertion succeed!"
    print browser.title
except AssertionError:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_tb(tb)  # Fixed format
    tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    filename, line, func, text = tb_info[-1]

    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text))
    exit(1)

print("Page Title is :", browser.title)
clear_cache_and_cookies(browser)

browser.get(url16)
print browser.title
print type(browser.title)
print u'New Tab'
print type(u'New Tab')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can't you just do: `window.chrome.webstore` = true ?

Comment: @pguardiario tried already that but it doesn't work. How to do that in Python? Also browser.execute_javascript(window.chrome.webstrore=true;) seems to have no effect at all. Any help, please? How to do it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  window.chrome.webstore = true
""")
```

Comment: Hi! I've just did it like you are saying but still not working: https://i.imgur.com/HAaYmxh.png

Comment: On real Chrome browser these variables are: window.chrome: [object Object]
window.chrome.webstore: undefined
window.chrome.runtime: [object Object]
window.CSS: function CSS() { [native code] } https://i.imgur.com/Q0aL5zm.png and on Selenium they are: https://i.imgur.com/7BcDGJp.png Any help, please? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @pcguardiario Sorry for coming back to this subject but didn't found any solution. Do you have any idea how to fix this, please? Thank you a lot in advance for you help!

Comment: You can set those things to whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, but How could I set them? driver.execute_script("""
  window.chrome.webstore = true
""") is not working. Is there any other way, please? Thank you in advance! @pcguardiario

Comment: I'm sorry, that is how you set it, it should work as long as window.chrome object exists.